# Java error - Syntax error on token VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: java, string, variable-declaration

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class Groceries{

   public int max = 10;
   public String[] fruit;

   private class FoodList{      
         fruit = new String[max];
  }
}
```

However, I have been getting the following error on the line where I initialize my array of fruits: `Syntax error on token "fruit", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`. Why could this be happening, and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Nice short example, thanks. `fruit = new String[max];` is a statement. It needs to go inside a method, not just inside an inner class (FoodList is an inner class). This is a commen error among learners of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for `FoodList` and put the initialisation in there.

```
public class Groceries {

    public int max = 10;
    public String[] fruit;

    private class FoodList {
        public FoodList() {
            fruit = new String[10];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code block and should be inside method/ constructor.

```
 fruit = new String[max];
```